# Can't click on my links after placing some images

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm new in html and css so i have a question.

I am messing around with some stuff but after placing some images on my page i can't click on my links anymore.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <title>Rijschool Houben</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="header-pic"><img src="image/test.png"></div>
    <p>
     <div id="nav-bar">
         <ul>
           <li>|<a href="http//www.google.nl">Home</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="contact">Info</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="portfolio">Prijzen</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="over ons">Acties</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="over ons">Machtiging</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="over ons">Theorie</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="over ons">Begeleid rijden</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="over ons">Bromfiets</a>|</li>
           <li><a href="over ons">Contact</a>|</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
   </p>
   <p>
     <div id="icon-main">
         <i class="fa fa-mobile" style="font-size:28px;"></i><a>046-4524501</a><br />
         <i class="fa fa-paste" style="font-size:18px;"></i><a>raymond@rijschoolhouben.nl</a><br />
         <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" style="font-size:20px;"></i><a>Volg ons op Facebook!</a>
     </div>
   </p>
   <p>
    <div id="img-1">
      <img src="image/1.jpg" alt="Scooter" width="330px" height="400px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="img-2">
      <img src="image/2.jpg" alt="Geslaagde 1" width="337px" height="400px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="img-3">
      <img src="image/3.jpg" alt="Geslaagde 2" width="337px" height="400px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="img-4">
      <img src="image/4.jpg" alt="Geslaagde 3" width="337px" height="400px" />
    </div>
    <div id="img-5">
      <img src="image/5.jpg" alt="Geslaagde 4" width="337px" height="400px" />
    </div>
    <div id="img-6">
      <img src="image/6.jpg" alt="Geslaagde 5" width="337px" height="400px" />
    </div>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

div#header-pic{
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  left: 500px;
}
div#nav-bar{
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 130px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div#nav-bar ul{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #323232;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

div#nav-bar li{
  display: inline;
}

div#nav-bar li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#icon-main{
  position: fixed;
  color: #323232;
  padding: 10px;
}

div#icon-main i{
  padding: 5px;
}

div#icon-main a{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#img-1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 184px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#img-2 {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 184px;
  padding-left: 255px;
}

div#img-3 {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 184px;
  padding-left: 915px;
}

div#img-4 {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 184px;
  padding-left: 585px;
}

div#img-5{
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 184px;
  padding-left: 1245px;
}

div#img-6 {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 184px;
  padding-left: 1575px;
}
```

i know the code is bad but i hope someone can help me!
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxy4y3ym/).

-Ryan

Comment: Please add the HTML and CSS to your question, using external hosts is frowned upon on Stackoverflow since links can break.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your external code.  Please add your HTML and CSS to your question in Stack Overflow.

From the external HTML you have the following code:

```
<a>046-4524501</a>
```

Which does not work as a link.

You have this code

```
<a href="http//www.google.nl">Home</a>
```

That works as you would expect it to.

Change this line:

```
<a>046-4524501</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http//www.example.com">046-4524501</a>
```

Where the href="Where you want the link to go".

It's all about the value for "href"

Answer (score 1):

You are placing divs containing the images using `padding`. That's why you can not use links in the menu. Div blocks cover your links.

Try using something like:

```
selector {
   position: absolute; /* or `fixed` like in your css; see below*/
   top: 100px; /* pixels from the top */
   left: 100px; /* pixels from the left */
   /* you can also use `bottom` and `right` */
}
```

For example:

```
div#img-3 { /* or just `#img-3`; see below */
  position: absolute;
  top: 184px;
  left: 915px;
}
```

Check this [w3 schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more information on positioning.

Not related to the question:

- If you are using CSS's **id** selector (#), I suggest not to use **element** selector (e.g. `div`). So rather than `div#img-3` try using just `#img-3`.
- Try avoiding using **id** selectors at all. You can use **class** rules, and happily after some time they will result in saving you a lot of work.
- If you are using HTML5 then try using [semantic elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp).
- Avoid using `fixed` position when you don't need to (your page is an example of such page).
- [Paragraphs](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp) (`p`) shouldn't be used in the same way as `div`. It may result in bad habit for semantic sites.
- Rather than using positioning (`position`), experiment with `float` or different `display` types (e.g. `inline-block`). Use it only when it is really needed.
- Read about [HTML Responsive Web](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).

Answer (score 1):

I did notice you are doing non-responsive html which means it is not mobile friendly or will look the same in smaller browser windows.

Your code is messy but your doing okay.

- First off wrap everything you are putting in the header in the header div
- The images are floating up to the top over your nav due to the position:fixed
- Remove all the empty `<p></p>` between your div's
- Use floats on your images and width of a percentage of 100% plus wrap them in a container/div

If you need me to I can see if I can redo all your html and CSS but think for you would learn better to try it out for yourself.

You could always go look at the [HTML5 boilerplate](http://komelin.com/en/5tips/5-most-popular-html5-responsive-frameworks) out there and use them to guide you on how to construct good code.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to create a row of images. Instead of using a system of DIVs why don't you use the more flexible (and more responsive) structure of a list?

Then you can use `float:` for lining them up in a row and basic CSS to give them sizes. The images will be specified as a background for these `li` elements (better practice).

Like this: http://codepen.io/Attrexx/pen/KVvwXP

Comment: I recommend marking one of the answers as a Best Answer therefore making your issue SOLVED, if that is the case.